# External display too slow to start

Tags: display, usb

I have a MacBook Air M1, 2020.
I recently changed my USB-C Hub as my last one comes to the end of its life :)
I now own the Anker 555.

I am looking to connect the Acer GN246HL with its HDMI connection. However, I learned that the screen does not support DP Alt-Mode, and is *extremely* slow to "start" (yes, it looks like the screen has to boot for a few seconds longer than the Mac itself).

While the starting latency never really caused me any problems, it appears that this time it is caused by the hub and/or the Mac to stop sending a signal to the screen. And so when the screen finally wakes up, receiving no signal anymore, it shuts down.

I am generally stuck in the following loop:

1. Plugging the screen into the hub
2. Screen starts
3. Hub/macOS impatiently waits
4. Then stops sending a signal
5. Screen wakes up, no signal, shut down
6. Hub detects screen waking up, sending signal again
7. Screen starts (back to #1)

I tried with other screens and the hub works perfectly fine.
I tried with Microsoft Windows and latency is always here, creating a problem as well. However, Windows was just waiting indefinitely, so I had to unplug/replug the screen and it worked fine.

I am not looking (yet) to buy a new screen. Is there a way I can screen my extremely slow screen and my impatient hub/macOS? Or any other solutions to fix the "loop" problem?

Comment: Try bypassing the hub and connect directly to the screen, doors the problem persist?

Comment: I don't have an HDMI port on the MacBook, and there is no USBC port on my screen... so I can't bypass it, unfortunately. However, the Hub worked perfectly with 3 other displays ;-)

Comment: Get a quality [USB-C to HDMI adapter](http://radnex.us/anker_usb-c_HDMI_4K) to ensure you’ve got a good signal going to the monitor.  Some hubs use inferior chipsets that can cause issues.